# Getting an error : ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/tracks") while installing TracksApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm trying to install [Tracks](https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks) on Nginx + Passenger and getting the following error when trying to access the site:
`The page you were looking for doesn't exist.`
When I check `/log/production.log` I see the following record:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/tracks"):
  actionpack (4.1.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
```

I suspect that issue that I trying to use sub-uri within my domain, i.e. `www.example.com/tracks`, for example in [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) I need to add the following lines at `environment.rb`:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.default_scope = { :path => '/redmine', :shallow_path => '/redmine' }
...
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Perhaps I need to make same changes at Tracks but I don't know rails.

This is config from `nginx.conf` responsible for this Tracks:

```
location /tracks {
           passenger_enabled on;
           alias   /opt/tracks/public;
           index  index.html index.htm;
       }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to my friend, he pointed me to this tutorial: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri following which I've changed in my `nginx.conf` section `location /tracks` to the following:

```
location /tracks {
          passenger_base_uri /tracks;
          passenger_app_root /opt/tracks;
          passenger_document_root /opt/tracks/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
          alias   /opt/tracks/public;
          index  index.html index.htm;
      }
```

It solved the issue.